# Transparent panel with Umano SlidingUpPanel

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a sliding layout using the Umano code: 
https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

It works perfectly, but I have one problem. My panel should be partly transparent, so the original view is still visible when it's up.

The view background is set properly to #64000000, but it is still completely opaque and nothing can be seen behind it.

Here's the code:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_up_panel"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/images_gallery_image" />

    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#64000000">

            <!-- MY STUFF (transparent stuff) -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I thought maybe the issue is caused by hiding of UI elements underneath the expanded panel, so I tried to play around in the library code, but it doesn't seem to be related.

While debugging, I have noticed that hasOpaqueBackground(View v) in line 355 of the library does return false, as expected - but the view still is opaque.

Comment: Have you found any solution to this? There seems to be a pull request: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/pull/49

Answer (score 10):

The support for this has been added in the library. Just set `overlay` attribute to true, and set the color of the panel to transparent.

Comment: How to pull the pane partially? I want to show the bottom pane only half of the screen.

Comment: Man..But I cant enable overlay ..as this create a gray shadow ..I need outside layout WHITE and sliding panel layout transparent...please do reply if it is possible

Comment: Which child should overlay be set to true ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, It seem's as if this feature was added before but it isnt in the code. I used the other version of SlidingUpPanelLayout.java [(here)](https://github.com/ShakeJ/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/blob/cf95b2af29c785e57e19871ba4ea9ad19a51fcf7/library/src/com/sothree/slidinguppanel/SlidingUpPanelLayout.java) and changed mIsTransparent to true <del>false</del>